# Detect IMAPI 2.0

Tags: c#, dvd-burning, cd-burning

Is there a way to detect what version of IMAPI is installed on an XP or Vista machine? I'm starting to try to burn CDs from an application I'm writing and I'm just kinda lost. I understand that in order to burn DVDs you have to have IMAPI 2.0, I just need to know where to find it or how to detect the version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this project, it utilizes the IMAPIv2.0 COM objects. In the examples in the article, you'll see that one of the first steps is wrapped in a try...catch and if that fails, then IMAPIv2.0 is not installed.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/imapi2.aspx